# big O-notation of a tree traversal method

Tags: math

What is the big O runtime complexity of a method which for every node in a tree-structure (in a preorder traversal) has to touch all ancestor nodes, too? O(n * avg(tree-height))? That is the runtime complexity of our method/function is in O(n * avg(tree-height))? (in the average case).

Maybe avg(tree-height) could be defined as (min + max) / 2, but hm

Answer (score 0):

I may have misunderstood, but if you're saying you need to go through all nodes (n) and then touch each anscestor per node (worst case: log n in a *balanced* binary tree) then I would think it would be `O(n*Log(n))`.  Constants do not apply to big O notation, but (as pointed out by @interjay below) averages could be.

Assuming an unbalanced tree, your worst case for touching all ancestors is approximately `n/2`, which is just n in big O.

Comment: Tree height can be up to `n` in an unbalanced tree. And averages can very well apply to big O.

Comment: I beat you to fixing the balanced issue :-)  I stand corrected on averages (and would love an example if it's simple).

Comment: I meant that you could say here that the runtime is `O(n * avg(node depth))` - this may be what the OP meant. The average node depth can range from O(log(n)) to O(n) depending on how balanced the tree is.

Comment: If your root node has 2 children, a single child on one side with the rest on the other, then an average of node depth isn't going to provide an upper bound.  You could calculate running time more precisely for given classes of input, but it defeats the simplicity of the notation.

Comment: ok, than probably my O(n^2) runtime complexity which I described in my thesis is ok (for general trees, must not be a balanced tree and no requirenment for a binary tree as well). That is an improvement from O(n^2) the algorithm described here (to adjust the numbers of descendants of a node during insertions of a first tree-structure) to O(n) that is just inserting nodes in a tree-structure in a preorder traversal (insertAsFirstChild() or insertAsRightSibling()) and then adjusting the descendant-count of each node during a postorder traversal.

Comment: and the worst case would be a linked list, that is 0 ancestors, 1, 2, 3, ..., n-1